# What is a "pitch period"?

Tags: audio, speech-processing, pitch, periodic, fundamental-frequency

The term **pitch period** appears in the book *Speech and Language Processing* by Daniel Jurafsy:

> As we just said, a pitch-synchronous algorithm is one in which we do
> something at each **pitch period** or epoch. For such algorithms it is
> important to have very accurate pitch markings: measurements of
> exactly where each pitch pulse or epoch occurs. An epoch can be deﬁned
> by the instant of maximum glottal pressure, or alternatively by the
> instant of glottal closure.

I have some difficulties to understand what a **pitch period** means here. Could someone please explain more about the concept of **pitch period** to me? Visualize an example of a **pitch period** in a graph like waveform or spectragram would be more helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based in @rbj answer, can i try to show you visually ...

Take a look in this pure tone signal, one sine at `100hz` and sample rate at `44100hz`.

[image]

just by looking you can find where the pattern starts to repeat itself,
I marked it with the naked eye as being in position `441`(Period)

So we take exactly `100hz` --> `44100/441=100hz`

Another example:

[image]

Another `100hz` signal, it was sampled at `48000hz`, one more time just looking the wavform signal i try mark where this start to be periodic, for my eyes i marked it at position `447`(Period)

So it give me `48000/477=±100hz` to be exact = `100.6289hz`

Comment: thanks！Is the term *pitch period* just the same as the term *period* ?

Comment: pitch and period can be equivalent terms, if you have the period you will be able to turn it into pitch and vice versa

Answer (score 4):

The **pitch period** of a perfectly periodic function, $x(t)$, is the smallest positive value $P>0$ such that

$$ x(t+P) = x(t) \qquad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} $$

Now, simply because a function is periodic with period $P$, then it is also periodic with periods $2P$ or $3P$ or $4P$ or any integer multiple of $P$, but we don't pick $2P$ or $3P$ or $4P$ for the period of $x(t)$, we pick the smallest possible $P$ that is a positive value.

The reciprocal of that period $P$ is the **fundamental frequency**

$$ f_0 \triangleq \frac{1}{P} $$

From that, it is possible to represent the period signal $x(t)$ as a **Fourier Series**

$$\begin{align}
x(t) &= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k \ e^{j 2 \pi k f_0 t} \\
\\
     &= c_0 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} |c_k| \cos(2 \pi k f_0 t + \phi_k) \qquad \phi_k = \arg\{c_k\} \\
\\
     &= c_0 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \big(\underbrace{|c_k|\cos(\phi_k)}_{a_k}\big) \cos(2 \pi k f_0 t) - \big(\underbrace{|c_k|\sin(\phi_k)}_{b_k}\big) \sin(2 \pi k f_0 t) \\
\\
     &= c_0 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \cos(2 \pi k f_0 t) - b_k \sin(2 \pi k f_0 t) \\
\end{align}$$

where $$ c_k = a_k + j\,b_k = \int\limits_{t_0}^{t_0+P} x(t) e^{-j 2 \pi k f_0 t} \ \mathrm{d}t \qquad t_0 \in \mathbb{R} $$

Now most audio that sounds like a note or a tone, including voiced speech, is not exactly periodic, but is *"quasi-periodic"*.  So our defining condition of a quasiperiodic $x(t)$ is

$$ x\big(t+P(t)\big) \approx x(t) \qquad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} $$

Now, instead of constant $P$, the period is a virtually constant (or slowly varying) function of time $P(t)$.  The fundamental frequency then would also be a virtually constant function of time

$$ f_0(t) \triangleq \frac{1}{P(t)} $$

Now the **pitch** of that tone or note is the logarithm of the fundamental frequency $f_0$.  If that pitch is expressed in units of *octaves*, it's the base-2 logarithm.  If the pitch is expressed in units of *semitones*, it's 12 times that base-2 logarithm.  The pitch has to be relative to a standard pitch.  For MIDI, the pitch is

$$ p(t) = 12 \log_2\left( \frac{f_0(t)}{440 \, \mathrm{Hz}} \right) + 69 $$

and is in units of semitones with Middle C having a pitch of $60$.

Comment: thanks！Is the term *pitch period* just the same as the term *period* ？

Comment: As far as i can tell.  It's also might not be a constant value like you would see in a perfectly periodic tone.  "period" might imply a constant value.  "pitch period" might imply a slowly varying value just as pitch is slowly varying.